# How do I compress numeric data points to a smaller set?

Tags: arrays, charts

Given an array of n floats, I'd like to create a new array of length m (where n is larger than m), so that when plotted on a line graph, the two graphs would overlap.

For example, given the following array and the new length 8:

`[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 14, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0]`

the result *may* be something like this:

`[1.8, 5.6, 9.4, 13.8, 13.8, 9.4, 5.6, 1.8]`

(I apologize, my math is really bad so the numbers are probably wrong)

Mathematical accuracy is less important than speed or memory considerations.

Answer (score 0):

In lieu of a better solution, here is a mathematically inaccurate implementation in ruby:

```
def interpolate(series, new_size)
  raise "new_size must be smaller than series size" if series.count < new_size

  ratio = (new_size / series.count.to_f).round
  res = []
  new_size.times do |i|
    idx = (i * ratio).round
    res << (((ratio * (series[idx] || 0)) + ((1 - ratio) * (series[idx + 1] || 0)) / 2))
  end
  res
end
```